# Determine the spacing length between word when the text is justified

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to reduce the spacing between words when content of the text is justified. I can do this by increase or decreasing the font size. The width of the content is fixed I cannot change that. Is there a way to determine the spacing between each word? With JS or using HTML canvas.  I also try to count the no-break space (U+00A0), not sure if that is even the right Unicode, between the word without success.

[image]

Comment: A few options to look at: [canvas.measureText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText). You could also wrap each word in a span and use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to determine its placement relative to others.

Comment: Could you put up your HTML/CSS just so we can make sure we are talking about the same formatting.